# Page Scrolling side to side

Tags: html, css

I have a page with code as shown below. My problem is it keeps scrolling side to side due to the fact that there is extra space in the right. I have set the with of the html to 100% and the width of the body to 1280px as shown below,I have also set the width of the biggest divs to 100%.

I am outputting some pictures in a for loop with ejs templating.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 margin:0 auto;
    /*padding:100;*/
    height:100%;
    width:1280px;
 background-color: #F8F8FF;
}

#content{
 overflow: auto;
 padding:10px;
 padding-bottom: 180px;
 width:100%;
}

#container{
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
 <%= include navbar %>
</div>

<div id="content">

 <h2><%= photographer_name %></h2>

 <% for(var i=0; i < stock.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="photo_div">

    <div style="height:300px" class="thumbnail">
     <img height="100%" src="/images/<%=profile[i].image_name%>">
    </div>

       <div class="caption">
        <h3><%= profile[i].product_name %></h3>
       </div>

  </div>
 <% } %>

</div>
```

can someone please explain why I am getting space on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding` is applied on the inside of the element. In your example this means that `#content`'s width is actually 100%+20px (1300px) which causes the scroll bar to appear.

`width` is not necessarily required on the `#content` and `#container` (depending on your content)

```css
    html {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 margin:0 auto;
    
    height:100%;
   /* width:1280px; removed for the SO snippet to show difference */
 background-color: #F8F8FF;
}

#content{
 overflow: auto;
 padding:10px;
 padding-bottom: 180px;
 /* Removed the width */
}

#container{
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
 /* Removed the width */
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
 <%= include navbar %>
</div>

<div id="content">

 <h2><%= photographer_name %></h2>

 <% for(var i=0; i < stock.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="photo_div">

    <div style="height:300px" class="thumbnail">
     <img height="100%" src="/images/<%=profile[i].image_name%>">
    </div>

       <div class="caption">
        <h3><%= profile[i].product_name %></h3>
       </div>

  </div>
 <% } %>

</div>
```

This keeps the padding but does not cause the addition of the width+padding+margin being over the 100%.

Answer (score 1):

2 things will cause a horizontal scroll bar with your CSS. If the browser is > 1280px, there is no horizontal scrolling. However, if the browser is < 1280px, there will be a horizontal scroll bar because of `body { width:1280px; }` and `#content` will be `100%` + `20px` wide because of the default box model and the `10px` padding.

To address it, I would change `body` to `max-width: 1280px` (so it will be `100%` width when the viewport is < `1280px`) and add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#content`